# GetData() error creating framebuffer

Tags: xna, android, opengl-es, opengl-es2, monogame

I'm currently porting a game written in C# with XNA library to Android with Monogame.
I have a `Texture2D` and i'm trying to get an array of `uint` in this way:

```
Texture2d textureDeform = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Texture/terrain");
uint[] pixelDeformData = new uint[textureDeform.Width * textureDeform.Height];
textureDeform.GetData(pixelDeformData, 0, textureDeform.Width * textureDeform.Height);
```

I get the following exception:

> System.Exception: Error creating framebuffer: Zero at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D.GetTextureData (Int32
>   ThreadPriorityLevel) [0x00000] in :0

I found that the problem is in `private byte[] GetTextureData(int ThreadPriorityLevel)` creating the `framebuffer`:

```
private byte[] GetTextureData(int ThreadPriorityLevel)
{
            int framebufferId = -1;
            int renderBufferID = -1;

            GL.GenFramebuffers(1, ref framebufferId);  // framebufferId is still -1 , why can't be created?
            GraphicsExtensions.CheckGLError();
            GL.BindFramebuffer(All.Framebuffer, framebufferId);
            GraphicsExtensions.CheckGLError();
            //renderBufferIDs = new int[currentRenderTargets];
            GL.GenRenderbuffers(1, ref renderBufferID);
            GraphicsExtensions.CheckGLError();

            // attach the texture to FBO color attachment point
            GL.FramebufferTexture2D(All.Framebuffer, All.ColorAttachment0,
                                    All.Texture2D, this.glTexture, 0);
            GraphicsExtensions.CheckGLError();

            // create a renderbuffer object to store depth info
            GL.BindRenderbuffer(All.Renderbuffer, renderBufferID);
            GraphicsExtensions.CheckGLError();
            GL.RenderbufferStorage(All.Renderbuffer, All.DepthComponent24Oes,
                                   Width, Height);
            GraphicsExtensions.CheckGLError();

            // attach the renderbuffer to depth attachment point
            GL.FramebufferRenderbuffer(All.Framebuffer, All.DepthAttachment,
                                       All.Renderbuffer, renderBufferID);
            GraphicsExtensions.CheckGLError();

            All status = GL.CheckFramebufferStatus(All.Framebuffer);

            if (status != All.FramebufferComplete)
                throw new Exception("Error creating framebuffer: " + status);

... 
}
```

The `frameBufferId` is still -1, seems that `framebuffer` could not be generated and I don't know why.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: It's possible that this feature isn't supported on Android. Maybe the MonoGame forums could help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how Monogame grabs pixel data under the hood, but to my knowledge, OpenGL ES2.0 doesn't really support grabbing pixel data from textures stored in video memory due to a lack of support for Pixel Buffer Objects. That being said, I'm not sure why this code fails to create a Frame Buffer Object

Comment: You may want to try catching a MonoGameGLException that gets thrown inside of GraphicsExtensions.CheckGLError() if there's a GL Error. This might give you more useful information

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is either about debugging your code for you or a Monogame bug.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the "ref" parameter. Your frame ID might be zero and when you use the "ref" it will add 0 + -1 = -1.. 
Microsoft example...

```
class RefExample
{
    static void Method(ref int i)
    {
        // Rest the mouse pointer over i to verify that it is an int. 
        // The following statement would cause a compiler error if i 
        // were boxed as an object.
        i = i + 44;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int val = 1;
        Method(ref val);
        Console.WriteLine(val);

        // Output: 45
    }
}
```